# Backbone: pass or retrieve details on a Collection update

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I think this gets my question across.

```
var coll = myBackboneCollection();
coll.on('update', this.collUpdated, this);
coll.create({ id: 1 });

collUpdated: function (collection, options) {
    var newId = ???;
}
```

I want to know that newId is 1 in the callback function. Is this possible? I'd prefer not to use a state variable on the Collection if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see in the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create), `create` only triggers the following directly:

> Creating a model will cause an immediate "add" event to be triggered on the collection, a "request" event as the new model is sent to the server, as well as a "sync" event, once the server has responded with the successful creation of the model

judging by that, you should be listening to the `add` event.

Also note that the signature of `create` method is `collection.create(attributes, [options])`.

So if you are trying to set the actual `id` property of the model, you should be passing it in the options as the second argument:

```
var coll = myBackboneCollection();
coll.on('add', this.collUpdated, this);
coll.create({},{ id: 1 });
collUpdated: function (model, collection, options) {
  if(model.id === 1){
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a fair answer to the question I asked, although it mostly revealed that my question wasn't specific enough. I didn't want to use the add event, but I eventually had to because there just isn't enough information passed to the update event. Also, I believe that the options that are passed to 'create' are forwarded to the create callback, not to the 'update' or 'add' callbacks.